# C#: Multithreaded (WMI) application locks up GUI

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, network-programming, wmi

I was wondering if anyone had any guidance on an issue I am having with the code below. The codes purpose is to:

- Load a list of 1000's of computers
- Collect information from them using WMI and Parallel.foreach()

  - Write this information to disk
- Update the listview in the main GUI with each computers status

The issue I am having is that **after connecting to around 1000 computers the main GUI application locks up**. To avoid the obvious GUI lockups **I have been using Invoke()** to update the main GUI.

This bug is hard to reproduce in a test environment as it happens after connecting to so many computers. My thoughts on the bug are that it may be one of the following (i'm not an expert):

- I have made a rookie mistake with the multithreading/Parallel.foreach()
- There are simply too many calls to Invoke() and the main GUI is busy with updating all the time
- I have used all available resources for the program (machine seems to have more RAM available)
- The processing done on remote computers is too slow (WAN links) *- why would this affect the main GUI?*

Here is the code, it starts with *ScanButton_Click()*:

```html
namespace WMIScan
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // ...Other code removed as it is irrelevant

        private void ScanButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*
             * Scan all computers in the list
             */
            List<string> computers = new List<string>();
            foreach (ListViewItem item in CompList1.Items)
            {
                computers.Add(item.Text);
                item.SubItems[1].Text = "";
                item.SubItems[2].Text = "";
                item.SubItems[3].Text = "";
            }
            LaunchScanning(computers);
        }

        private void LaunchScanning(List<string> computers)
        {
            /*
             * This function is responsible for launching a scan against all computers in the list
             * It handles the multithreading of scan jobs.
             */
            toolStripProgressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0;
            toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = computers.Count;
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task Processing;

            //Support the scanning of multiple computers.
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Scanning of " + computers.Count + " computers(s) started at: " + DateTime.Now;
            Processing = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(computers, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = max_threads }, computer =>
                    {
                        BeginScanning(computer);
                        toolStripProgressBar1.GetCurrentParent().BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { toolStripProgressBar1.Value++; }));
                    });
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Scanning of " + computers.Count + " computers(s) completed.";
                }
            );
            
        }

        private void BeginScanning(string computer)
        {
            /*
             * This function is responsible for conducting the scanning of a single computer
             */
            ManagementScope cimv2_scope = new ManagementScope();
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            ObjectQuery query;
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher;
            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection;
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = null;
            string completed_jobs = "";
            string errors = "";
            string[] listview_output = { "", "","" };

            //Check if credentials have been provided.
            if (username != "" && password != "")
            {
                options.Username = username;
                options.Password = password;
            }

            //Attempt inital connection
            cimv2_scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + computer + @"\root\CIMV2", options);
            try
            {
                //Create new scope connections
                cimv2_scope.Connect();

                //Attempt to open output file.
                try
                {
                    file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(output_dir + @"\" + computer + ".txt");
                    file.WriteLine("######Start " + DateTime.Now);

                    //Query Operating System
                    try
                    {
                        query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
                        searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(cimv2_scope, query);
                        queryCollection = searcher.Get();
                        foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
                        {
                            DateTime InstallDate = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(m["InstallDate"].ToString());
                            DateTime LastBootUpTime = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(m["LastBootUpTime"].ToString());
                            DateTime LocalDateTime = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(m["LocalDateTime"].ToString());
                            file.WriteLine("OS," + computer + "," + m["CSName"] + "," + m["BuildNumber"] + "," + m["Caption"]
                                + "," + m["Version"] + "," + m["OSArchitecture"] + "," + m["ServicePackMajorVersion"] + ","
                                + m["ServicePackMinorVersion"] + "," + m["CurrentTimeZone"] + "," + InstallDate + "," +
                                LastBootUpTime + "," + LocalDateTime + "," + m["OSLanguage"] + "," + m["OSProductSuite"] +
                                "," + m["OSType"] + "," + m["RegisteredUser"] + "," + m["SerialNumber"] + "," + m["SystemDevice"]
                                + "," + m["SystemDirectory"] + "," + m["SystemDrive"] + "," + m["WindowsDirectory"]);
                        }
                        completed_jobs = "OS";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        errors += ("[Operating System] " + e.Message);
                    }

                    // ... Many more WMI queries here
                   
                    //Processing completed
                    file.WriteLine("Completed " + DateTime.Now);
                    file.Close();

                    CompList1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        ListViewItem tmp = CompList1.FindItemWithText(computer);
                        tmp.SubItems[1].Text = "True";
                        tmp.SubItems[2].Text = completed_jobs;
                        tmp.SubItems[3].Text = errors;
                    }));
                }
                catch (Exception e) //File Open Error
                {
                    CompList1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        ListViewItem tmp = CompList1.FindItemWithText(computer);
                        tmp.SubItems[1].Text = "Failed";
                        tmp.SubItems[2].Text = "";
                        tmp.SubItems[3].Text = e.Message;
                    }));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) //Scope Connection Error
            {
                CompList1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    ListViewItem tmp = CompList1.FindItemWithText(computer);
                    tmp.SubItems[1].Text = "Failed";
                    tmp.SubItems[2].Text = "";
                    tmp.SubItems[3].Text = e.Message;
                }));
            }
        }
     }
}
```

I'm new to C# and StackOverflow, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Joss

Comment: Sure, you are fire-hosing the UI thread with, roughly, updates 50 times faster than your eye can see.  This is not useful of course, not to your eyes and definitely not to the UI thread which is completely swamped and burning 100% core.  Collect the results in a List, update the UI once in a while.

Comment: Interesting point, if it is indeed the issue I assume I should have a thread responsible for collecting the information from the Parallel.Foreach() tasks and then periodically doing the update to the GUI? Any recommendations for queuing?

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know , Parallel.ForEach runs against how many cores you have. ie. if you have 4 cores, you will be able to process in 4 threads in parallel.

Why don't you do a foreach and create a Task for each operation that you wish to process.
(i've not tested this, but you get the idea)

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();


    foreach(var computer in computers)
    {
      var t =Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        BeginScanning(computer);

                         Acttion myUiStuff = () =>
                         {
                            toolStripProgressBar1.Value++;
                            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Scanning of " + computers.Count + " computers(s) completed.";
                         };

                         //im assuming you are using WinForms; UI objects must be modified by UI thread so thats is the call to BeginInvoke; If its WPF call the Dispatcher.
                         BeginInvoke(myUiStuff);
                    }
      tasks.Add(t);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: You don't explain why this would solve the OP's problem. Simply rewriting the code for no apparent reason isn't much of an answer, is it?

Comment: Yes it's WinForms. The BeginScanning() will only scan one computer, that's why I had to add the Parrallel.ForEach() to work on each independent computer; the Task.Factory.StartNew() ensures the GUI thread is not responsible for all of this activity (avoid lock-up). Thank you for the information, I didn't know you could use BeginInvoke() like that.

Comment: @jalf instead of commenting my comment, why don't you reply with at least an answer. Simply commenting on answers isn't helping much is it?

Comment: @Alex Peta: appreciate your proposed answer nevertheless.

Comment: @Joss cheers, im at work and dont have the environment setup etc. just writing this without testing .

Comment: @AlexPeta *because*, as radical a notion as it may be to you, my interest was not in harvesting rep for myself, but in helping *you* improve *your* answer. So perhaps you could drop the attitude? Thank you. A bad answer is a waste of the reader's time. A comment is just a comment.

Comment: @jalf first of all , the fact the somebody took the time to write a simple idea to help another is reason enough to appreciate. If its not THE full answer, it is still helpful. Second, if you want to help improve an answer, why dont you tell / show me how ? instead of a snarky comment that frankly doesnt really help me in any way shape or form. Its just comment trolling. Dont you agree?

Comment: No, I do not agree. I told you exactly why I thought this answer was problematic. If you are not able to improve your answer based on that, that is *your* problem, not mine. If you want me to clarify what I think should be changed, then feel free to ask me. Instead, *you* jumped to snarky comments. My comment was not intended as snark. It said precisely why I thought this was a bad answer.

Comment: I'll gladly repeat it though: you are simply saying "rewrite your function to do the same but with different API calls", with no explanation of why that would be expected to work better, or what was wrong with the OP's code.